# Pass and execute commands on Firefox Developer Toolbar through javascript or java?

Tags: java, javascript, mozilla

Lately I have been working over a project that automates navigating to various pages and then handling commands in between which need me to execute commands over the **Developer Toolbar** in Firefox (Shift+F2) thing.
I am not sure how to execute them through javascript/Java ? Can anybody help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is a web browser automation tool that meets your need here.

There is also a Firefox Addon called SeleniumIDE and Selenium library for Java, or Javascript (Node), you can get it at their [download page](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: Thanx for the reply mate ! I am already using Sahi wherever possible but the Developer toolbar will not be accessible though Selenium/Sahi as it is windows component.

Comment: When you execute commands over the Developer Toolbar, it acctually executes the javascript, so I think the point here is not to access the Developer toolbar but execute javascript in the content, am I get it right?. Selenium/Sahi are able to execute javascript on the browser, check this out: http://sahi.co.in/w/_call.

Comment: No its not the same. Actually the developer toolbar has some api fed in. I want to access those api. I dont want to write them all from scratch and execute them from Sahi. If at all those api are in some .js file, I dont know where to get them !